# Eclipse: How to close an Eclipse E4 part in SWTBot

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, e4, swtbot

I am writing SWTBot test case for my Eclipse E4 application.

In by setUp() (annotated with @Before), I am opening the part using the menu. I would like to close the same in tearDown (annotated with @After).

I tried with SWTWorkbenchBot, get the active view and close it but the active view instance is null. The view is in fact view and in focus. I can see it.

The code I have tried

```
SWTWorkbenchBot wbBot = new SWTWorkbenchBot();
SWTBotView botView = wbBot.activeView();
botView.close();
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating `SWTWorkbenchBot` reference in setUp() method before your UI is up. This should mostly solve your problem.
Also after making this change you can try using `WidgetMatcherFactory`:

```
workBenchBot.widget(org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.matchers.WidgetMatcherFactory.widgetOfType( <View_Name>.class ) );
```

Replace  with name of your view. It should return an instance of type `View_Name`. Then you should create an instance of `SWTBOTView` using your view (`View_Name`) and call `SWTBOTView#close()`

Hope this helps.